# Incorrect date difference in seconds in Hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to calculate the difference in seconds between 2 dates in hive. I found that one of the records is being calculated incorrectly, and I can't understand why or how to fix it.

The example is as follows:

```
select '2020-03-08 03:00:48' as stop_time,    
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-08 03:00:48') as stop_timestamp,    
'2020-03-08 02:45:03' as start_time,    
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-08 02:45:03') as start_timestamp,    
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-08 03:00:48') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-08 02:45:03') as difference
```

I am getting a result of -2,655 instead of +945

Any advise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of daylight savings time change. The place where you're located has day lights savings time that changed during 8 March, 2020 at the same hour. So, it is calculating different timestamp for `start_timestamp`.